# Unable to return none for data from list of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, while-loop, tuples

My function should take a list of tuples and return the number of days it takes for vehicles to reach or exceed n, starting from the first day in a list, using only a while loop and just one return statement.

```
def days_to_reach_n_vehicles(vehicle_records, n):
    """Returns number of days taken to reach or exceed a total of n vehicles"""
    cumulative_total = 0
    num_days = 0
    index = 0

    while index < len(vehicle_records):
        cumulative_total += vehicle_records[index][1]
        index += 1
        num_days += 1

        if cumulative_total >= n:
            break

    return num_days
```

It gives me a correct output of 2 for the following test code:

```
some_records = [('2010-01-01',1),
                ('2010-01-02',2),
                ('2010-01-03',3)]
days = days_to_reach_n_vehicles(some_records, 3)
print(days)
```

However it needs to return None if n vehicles are not reached by the last day in vehicle_records. I can't get it to return None for the next test data, can someone please tell me what I need to fix?

```
some_records = [('2010-01-01',1),
                ('2010-01-02',2),
                ('2010-01-03',3)]
days = days_to_reach_n_vehicles(some_records, 40)
print(days)
```

Comment: I get an output of 1 for your test code

Comment: In which situations should None be returned?

Comment: I think you need to move your `return num_days` back an indentation. At the moment it returns on the first iteration every time. Or depending on what you want - you might want to put it within your `if cumulative_total >= n:` block. Edit: I see you've changed this now.

Comment: @Matt If n vehicles are not reached by the last day in vehicle_records then a result of None should be returned

Comment: `return num_days if cumulative_total >= n else None` Should be what you're looking for.

Comment: Replace your `break` with `return num_days`. And don't have a second return - the function will automatically return `None`. This should fix it.

Comment: @RobertSeaman how can I change it to return the date instead of the days, for eg. if for the first test code above I need it to return 2010-01-02

Comment: @lpe97, your `num_days` is the same as `index`. Remove `num_days` entirely, and `return vehicle_records[index][0]`. Then move `index += 1` to the end of your `while` block. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you need to `return num_days if cumulative_total >= n else None`.

```
def days_to_reach_n_vehicles(vehicle_records, n):
    """Returns number of days taken to reach or exceed a total of n vehicles"""
    cumulative_total = 0
    num_days = 0
    index = 0

    while index < len(vehicle_records):
        cumulative_total += vehicle_records[index][1]
        index += 1
        num_days += 1

        if cumulative_total >= n:
            break

    return num_days if cumulative_total >= n else None
```

Comment: How can I change this to return the date instead of the number of days, for example for the first test code above, I need it to return 2010-01-02

Comment: before break, set `date_var = vehicle_records[index][0]` and `return date_var` instead.  Also, when you initialize those zero values initialize `date_var = None`.  You can remove the `if cumulative_total >= n else None` from your return statement since `date_var` will be `None` unless you hit that break

Comment: I need it to return the date where the total number of vehicles reaches or exceeds n. Currently for the above test code (n=3) it is returning 2010-01-03 and not 2010-01-02, can you please tell me where it needs to be change?

Comment: Can you post a new question?  Just to make this cleaner.  The text editor for comments isn't very easy to use (when writing code)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a for loop to iterate on the record like this:

```
def days_to_reach_n_vehicles(vehicle_records, n):
    """Returns number of days taken to reach or exceed a total of n vehicles"""
    cumulative_total = 0
    num_days = 0

    for date, number_of_vehicle in vehicle_records:
        cumulative_total += number_of_vehicle
        num_days += 1
        if cumulative_total >= n:
            break
    else:
        num_days = None  # a break never happens in the loop

    return num_days
```

And if you want to have some python fun:

```
from itertools import accumulate

def days_to_reach_n_vehicles(vehicle_records, n):
    n_vehicule_per_day = list(zip(*vehicle_records))[1]
    for num_days, cumsum in enumerate(accumulate(n_vehicule_per_day)):
        if cumsum >= n: return num_days + 1
    return None
```